# Why does collision detection work in editor but not in android build? (AR Foundation)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, game-physics, android-augmented-reality

I am building an augmented reality app using ar foundation. I need to detect a collision between two cubes. The cubes both have a box collider and a rigid body attached to them. When I run the scene in the editor everything works fine but when I build it for android and then test it won't detect any collisions. Could it be because when one of the cubes is spawned it is already touching the other one?

[image]

I'm pretty sure its an issue with Unity and not my code but here is some of it just in case.
I have also posted on Unity Answers [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1788118/why-does-collision-detection-work-in-editor-but-no.html)

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{

    Debug.Log(collision.gameobject.name);
    
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == col_tag)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject != first && first != null)
        {
            //stuff
        }
        else
        {
            point = collision.contacts[0].point;
            first = collision.gameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using void OnTriggerEnter. In the box collider activate IsTrigger and try to use this script:

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider collision)
{

    Debug.Log(collision.gameobject.name);
    
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "col_tag")
    {
        if (collision.gameObject != first && first != null)
        {
            //stuff
        }
        else
        {
            point = collision.contacts[0].point;
            first = collision.gameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can two triggers trigger each other? I thought one of them had to not be a trigger? Also, I don't think colliders have contact points but maybe I could use a raycast.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with 2020(because what isn't?), I'll switch to 2019 and see if it works.

Comment: I'm using 2020, and not face such an issue